# XDocument.Root : Possible System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, resharper

It looks like R# is detecting a possible null reference in the following code:

```
var importedDoc = XDocument.Parse(importedXml);
var importedElements = importedDoc.Root.Elements().ToList();
```

When accessing `importedDoc.Root` property. The awkward thing is that now I want to unit-test my method but I'm not able to pass `importedXml` so that the resulting `XDocument.Root` throws `NullReferenceException`. I have added null-checking code to throw exception if that is the case and I want to cover that branch:

```
if (importedDoc.Root == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException("There is no root element");
```

Can anyone provide a way to make this happen or, if not, at least explain how does R# come up with this code warning? Is the `Root` property not marked **[NotNull]** because there might be a different way to construct `XDocument` in which `Root` actually is `null`? If so, is not this a bug in `System.Xml.Linq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resharper doesn't know about any type of runtime checks `XDocument.Parse` may or may not do to ensure there is a root level element. It just sees `XDocument.Parse` as the invocation of a function that may return null and suggests you should test for a null condition where you actually use a member of the returned object.

since `importedDoc.Root` realistically can't be null since XDocument.Parse will throw when doing the parse in that case, you can either turn off the resharper warning with a comment

```
// ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
var importedElements = importedDoc.Root.Elements().ToList();
```

or you could just add the null checks yourself and re-raise the exception if you want like this to make resharper happy:

```
var importedDoc = XDocument.Parse(importedXml);
var importedElements = importedDoc?.Root?.Elements().ToList() ?? new List<XElement>();

if (importedElements.Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("No root");
```

or you could totally ignore the whole thing knowing that this particular warning isn't completely valid in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The specific reason why you get this warning is that R#'s external annotations for `XDocument.Root` say that it can be null. [R#s external annotations are open-sourced](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/05/25/open-sourcing-resharpers-external-annotations/), so you can see the item for yourself [here on github](https://github.com/JetBrains/ExternalAnnotations/blob/master/Annotations/.NETFramework/System.Xml.Linq/4.0.0.0.Nullness.Gen.xml) (line 214 at the time of writing).

Now, in this particular code path (creating the `XDocument` via `Parse`), examination of the decompiled code reveals that `Root` *in thie case* can never be `null`, since `XDocument.Load` will throw if it finds that `Root` is `null` after the load is complete; but that's not to say that `Root` can never *ever* be `null`. Therefore a one-off R# warning suppression seems most appropriate.